# How to add a read more in description in product page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

My product's description is too long, because of that, i really want to add something like read more button... the content can be extended only if someone click on the read more button?

I'm using magento2

Answer (score 0):

This is the one we use. 
Put the things you want hidden in your click here for more button in between `<div class="block-content">` and the first `</div>`

```
<div class="collapsible">
<p style="text-align: center;"><button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Click here for more...</button></p>
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
<div class="block-content">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But where and how to add this code ?

Comment: In your description